# Subdomain login problems

Tags: multisite, login, subdomains, cookies

Tonight I installed a clean copy of WordPress on my local machine, with the intent of trying to set up a subdomain multisite installation. (I've got lots of experience using subdirectories, but this is my first time using subdomains.)

I set up the following hostnames in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 multi
127.0.0.1 snoopy.multi
127.0.0.1 robots.multi
```

I installed WordPress and set up multisite as per the [Codex's Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) page.  I set up my Apache config so that `snoopy.multi` and `robots.multi` pointed to the same directory as `multi`.  I signed in to `http://multi/wp-admin/` and set up sites at `snoopy.multi` and `robots.multi`.  Everything worked fine -- the new sites showed up in My Sites.

Only I couldn't log in to the subdomains' `/wp-admin`.  If I entered the username and password that logged me in to the root site, I'd simply be redirected back to the login page.  (Entering a bogus password *did* trigger the "can't log you in" message, though, which was weird.)

I did find a solution, and will post it as an answer here, in case anyone else runs into this issue.  (That's kosher, right?  I did a search to see if it had been answered before, but didn't find anything that sounded like *exactly* the same issue. If I'm wrong, please let me know.)

**Edit**

The solution below is apparently not a complete solution; I can log in to the subdomains' `wp-admin` pages, but now I'm unable to log in to the root site's `wp-admin` pages at `http://multi/wp-admin` .  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are nested subdomains possible with a subdomain multisite?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140767/are-nested-subdomains-possible-with-a-subdomain-multisite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google led me to this page: http://lauragentry.com/blog/2012/01/05/when-wordpress-network-subdomain-blogs-wont-let-you-log-in/

There's a chunk of code in there that I added to my `wp-config.php` file, to wit:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

What I don't quite understand is *why* this works.  Anyone know?

**Updated** It doesn't *completely* work -- I can now log in to the subdomains, but not the root domain.

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer have you considered adding a bounty to your question?

Comment: If I recall correctly (and there's no guarantee of that; this was 3+ years ago) the eventual solution was "wipe and reinstall", which wasn't that big a hardship because this was a local test installation.

Comment: Then can yoi accept your own question?

Comment: I'd have *sworn* I did. Whoops.