# Are nested subdomains possible with a subdomain multisite?

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I currently have a multisite using sub domains setup, which works well so far:

```
example.com (main site)
site1.example.com 
site2.example.com
site3.example.com
```

The question now is whether it's possible to add a new, separate site using the URL

```
en.site1.example.com
```

When I try to create the site in my network, I get the error

```
Missing or invalid site address
```

Is multisite designed to work with a setup like this?

Comment: While it is possible, it can get
complicated very quickly, however, this plugin (free) https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/ and this ($25.95) http://wpebooks.com/networks/ allow you to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @G.M. If there's one thing I dread it's adding yet another plugin to a website. Luckily I don't need nested domains after all. Phew.

Answer (score 9):

By now, it is possible without any plugin. WordPress allows you to edit a sites domain and path free of any restrictions once it is created.

First of all: create a new site with an arbitrary but valid subdomain:

[image: Add a new site]

After the site was created follow the »edit site« link in the confirmation message. Here you can alter the domain and/or path on your own behalf. (The default rewrite rules of a sub-domain install does not work with a path other than `/`.) In your case change the domain to `en.site1.example.com`. Keep the option »Update `siteurl` and `home` as well.« checked!

[image: Change the sites URL]

Of course, you have to make sure that the subdomain will be resolved to the host driving your WordPress install. In my local example (en.site1.wp.tmp) I added the following line to the  /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    en.site1.wp.tmp
```

Now your site should be accessible via `en.site1.example.com` (or in my example `en.site1.wp.tmp`):

[image: The site under the new domain]

If you changed the URL of a site with existing content, you might want to update references to the old URL in the WordPress database. You can use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org) for that:

```
wp search-replace en-site1.example.com en.site1.example.com --network --precise --dry-run
```

The [`--dry-run`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) gives you an overview of the table columns that will be affected without actually changing anything. After you backed up your data, and you double-checked your parameter, run the command without this parameter.