# Wordpress multisite with only two level of sub-domains?

Tags: multisite

I've just set up WordPress 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 16.04, and configured it for Multisite using sub-domains.

I can browse to wordpress.mycompany.com/wp-admin and things work fine.

If I select Sites -> Add New Site,  I am aksed for the site address and it is always xxx.wordpress.mycompany.com however I do not want 3 levels of sub-domains.  I'd rather have Site1.mycompany.com and Site2.mycompany.com.   Is this possible, and if so how do I achieve that?  Documentation I've seen on the internet always seems to assume 4 3 levels of sub-domains.

Comment: No limit to create a sub-domains multisite but it's depends on server space. if your server space is not enough then not possible.

Comment: @PatelJignesh - that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find out how to do this automatically, but you can do it manually:  Go to **Network Admin » Sites** and then click **Edit** on the site whose URL you want to change.

You'll need to make sure that your DNS is set correctly.

See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184667/16121) (to a question that's pretty much the inverse of yours) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial setup should have been toplevel, not a subdomain.  ie (www.example.com or example.com)  That's where your problem is.  Right now wordpress thinks your toplevel is wordpress.example.com.  and then it's adding subdomains to that.