# Mapping domains to WordPress network installed on subdomain

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have a WordPress multisite with some sites inside it.
The WordPress multisite itself is installed in a subdomain: wp.domain.com
I want to map each site's domain to the corresponding site so I'm trying to set my DNS records to map domain1.com to wp.domain.com/site1 but I'm failing to figure out how, any suggestions?

I've used [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions/) guide for setting up my domain mapping.

Comment: Have you read this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140767/are-nested-subdomains-possible-with-a-subdomain-multisite/184667#184667 and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181914/what-is-the-correct-way-to-map-multiple-domains-in-a-wordpress-4-1-multisite-ins/182467#182467

Comment: They dont apply to my question. They refer to setting up sites inside a multisite network, my question regards mapping a domain to a wordpress multisite that's installed in a subdomain.

Comment: Yes, mapping a domain is a part of the MU settings.

Comment: The question isn't how to map a domain to a site inside a multisite network; but how to map it to a multisite network that sits inside a subdomain. It's a different thing and adds complexity to the mapping.

Comment: You mean you will use a domain for an network and another domain for an additional network? Then you should see at Multinetwork - https://github.com/stuttter/wp-multi-network

Comment: I think my question is pretty clear and it mentions nothing about multiple networks.